# Calling C# method from java it is good?

Tags: java, c#, .net

I know that we can call a C# method from a Java program.

I want to know if it will affect the performance of the Java program. Also, do you recommend using it or not?

Comment: Why the C++ tag, if the question is about C#/Java?

Comment: yes it's not good call c# method from java , you will lose soem performance

Comment: I think maybe if someone expert in c++ could have a good opinion about it

Comment: You can imagine that calling methods within the same program is always faster than calling a method from another executable/library, regardless of the language. And you can imagine that no one would recommend using two different languages for a solution. If you have a more specific situation, perhaps there is a more specific answer.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I am asking this question because I want to rewrite some c# classes in java and I do not know anything about c#,l.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis also is C# easy to learn or not ?

Comment: You'll find alot of similarities between C# and java. There's a chapter on MSDN for java developers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms228358(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @C.Evenhuis thanks